# Sentence Generation using stanford parser

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to generate similar kind of sentences using Stanford parser.
Steps :

1.Parse input sentence using Stanford library.

2.Generate production rules from parsed sentences

3.Replace some terminal values

4.Regenerate sentences using generate() function from nltk.parse.generate

I have three doubts:

1.Does StanfordParser always generate finite production rules?

2.While using generate function, for few sentences I am getting the following error.

"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

When I set recursion limit using sys.setrecursionlimit(0x10000000), I got Error: " Segmentation fault: 11"

2.1 Can I increase Recursion limit?

2.2 How can I solve this problem?

3 Is this the right approach? How can I improve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

The fuction [`nltk.parse.generate.generate()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#nltk.parse.generate.generate) is meant to generate *all* the productions of the grammar. This means that even a single recursive rule, such as an NP inside an NP (which happens all the time) will give you infinite recursion. As the documentation indicates, you can control it by limiting the depth of recursion (e.g., `depth=20`). If you wish you can also specify the number of trees you want to generate (`n=100`).

The limits will solve the infinite recursion problem, but they don't guarantee that you'll like the results. `generate()` inserts all possible expansions in order, so if the first rule is recursive, it will be used again and again. You'll probably get better results if you select the 50th tree generated, for example; but you'll certainly get the best results if you examine the structure of the grammar you generated, and code your own generator that makes random choices among the possible expansions.

Comment: Thank you, depth=20 worked but the problem is single recursive rule creates loop. eg. for "What is the price of large latte" sentence it is generating "What is the price of the price of the price of the price of the price of the price of the price of large price" is there any solution to handle this repetitive phrase problem. Is there any better parser which should be used?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the parser, or with the rules. The problem is that `generate()` is supposed to produce all possible expansions, so it chooses rules in order. Added discussion.